# How to reset a specified file in Eclipse?

Tags: git, eclipse, egit

How to reset a specified file in **Eclipse** like the command

```bash
git reset <commitID> <fileName>
```

do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either click on the file with the right mouse button in the commit view and select "Replace with HEAD version" or right-click on the file contents and select "Replace with" > "Branch, Tag or Reference" or "Commit...",